# Passing a variable and optionmenu selection to method

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an Optionmenu-Widget work with passing variables to a function.
I need to pass two variables when a user clicks an option in the menu.

```
    self.frameX = Frame(self.frameTwo, background="red", width= 370, height=35)
    self.frameX.pack_propagate(0)
    self.frameX.pack(side=TOP)

    self.names = [1,2,3,4,5]

    #Just for demonstration, some random number i 
    #should be saved and passed onchange optionmenu.
    i = random.randint(0, 10)

    self.var = StringVar()
    self.var.set("Numbers")

    #When the user selects an option, this function should 
    #pass i and the variable, which is what the user selected to the callback function.
    self.var.trace("w", lambda i=i:  self.callback(i, self.var.get()))

    self.options = OptionMenu(self.frameX, self.var, *self.names)
    self.options.place(x=180, y=5)
    self.options.pack()

    self.frameX.pack()

def callback(self, n, g):
    print(n)
    print(g)
```

If anyone could help me out with this, that would be great and appreciated alot.

Comment: It seems there is some code missing, could you please post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added the self.names list. The only ting missing is the frameX, but it's not that important for this particular case?

Comment: I am not very familiar with tkinter but I find your problem interesting. A MCVE would be nice so people like me can help you.

Comment: Okey I updated it again. I hope this is minimalistic and informative :)

Comment: Where is the class for "self"? Your code cannot run on its own.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to do something like this:

```
import random
from Tkinter import *

def callback(sv, i):
    print sv.get() + str(i);

master = Tk()

i = random.randint(0, 10)

variable = StringVar(master)
variable.set("one")  # default value
variable.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=variable: callback(sv, i))
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, "one", "two", "three")
w.pack()

mainloop()
```

As you can see, I pass the stringVar itself so I can call `get()` and other functions in the callback

Changing the OptionsMenu-Value prints e.g

```
>>two6
>>one6
>>three6
```